# Laravel get routes work, post don't

Tags: php, post, get, routes, laravel

I just can't figure it out, why on my local environment the following routes work perfectly.... and on a Staging environment I have been provided, to test the code, it doesn't work as supposed to

Routes:

```
Route::controller(Controller::detect());

...

Route::get('api', array(
        'as' => 'api_index',
        'uses' => 'api@index',
));

Route::get('api/(:any)/(:any)', 'api.(:1)@(:2)');
Route::post('api/(:any)/(:any)', 'api.(:1)@(:2)');
Route::put('api/(:any)/(:any)', 'api.(:1)@(:2)');
Route::delete('api/(:any)/(:any)', 'api.(:1)@(:2)');
```

The problem stands at my post requests, as they just won't be found and always returning a 404 no mather the request. Example:

- `POST` `http://staging.test.com/api` -> 404
- `POST` `http://staging.test.com/api/user` -> 404
- `POST` `http://staging.test.com/api/user/session` -> 404

Where all of the above tests, work in my local environment. The `GET` method works (the only one besides `POST` that I have tested)

So what am I missing?

### UPDATE

Tried changing the order of the `Routes::`, and tried the different methods... but still the same result

Comment: Controller::detect() is known to be buggy - just put in all your controllers manually.

Comment: After the `controller:detect()` I added `Route::controller(array('api.user', 'api.device'));` and still get the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as @TheShiftExchange said, it seams to be the buggy `Controller::detect()`'s fault.

Have tried also:

```
Route::controller(array('api.user', 'api.device'));
```

But only got it to work with:

```
Route::controller('api.user');
Route::controller('api.device');
```