# laravel 5.1 Route::post not working randomly

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5.1

When I left work yesterday the routeing worked perfectly. I haven't touched it since, and the only thing I did after I tested the site (and it worked) was make a new model and migration using `php artisan make:model`.

When I came in to work, about 35 minuets ago, poof. site doesn't work. the routes work with a get method (`Route::get('/', 'blahContoller@index')` but fails on ALL the `Route::post` methods. I'm stumped. Going back to laravel 5 after this project, 5.1 is unbelievably broken and worse then 5.0 and has casued me no end of problems that actually wastes more time then laravel is supposed to save.

The error I get:

> NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 143

my routes:

```
Route::get('/', 'TurboController@index');

Route::post('checkout', 'TurboController@checkout');
Route::post('securePayment', 'TurboController@securePayment');

Route::get('thankYou', function(){
    return view('thankYou');
});
```

I dont understand, I havent touched the route file since yesterday at 9:00am and worked up until I tested it today.

***I HAVE TRYED DUMPAUTOLOAD*** before you ask ;)

Comment: First off, this question should be flagged because it holds no question. Secondly on what url do you get the error and which request method is used while requesting this page.

Comment: Also did you check [this question and accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810009/laravel-get-routes-work-post-dont?rq=1)?

Comment: any route using Route::post doesn't work, so `localhost:8000/checkout` and `localhost:8000/securePayment`. I use a post method in my form.

Comment: can you give the exact version of laravel you are using `php artisan -V` and does the route work when using a default port 80?

Comment: I'm using laravel 5.1.2 - And no, the same result on default port

Comment: Have you tried clearing route cache (`artisan route:clear`)? If this doesn't help, post `artisan route:list` output.

Comment: I have done both, Routes Work fine. I have although found the issue and solved it. The problem was that when using `action="{{ url('/checkout') }}"` it , for some reason was going to ***checkout.html*** not ***checkout*** ,  I have managed to fix this however. very strange that it was adding ***.html*** to my route :P

Answer (score 0):

try to run these in terminal

php artisan clear-compiled, php artisan cache:clear, php artisan route:clear

Comment: Even Ihave this issues When I submit a form with method=patch or post its throwing me the same error